# How the Dwl code be altered to manipulate with empty spaces to match desired length?

Tags: mule, dataweave

Our requirement is to convert XML to fixed length (Cobol Copy Book). I am using dataweave for transformation.

[image]

As per the copy book schema, maximum occurrence of “EmpNumArray” is 2. The transformation working fine if the corresponding repeated element(EmpNumArray) in the input xml occurs 2 times.

But most of the time we only get one occurrence of “EmpNumArray”, in this scenario – transformation failed with the error “”.

Question: How the Dwl code be altered to manipulate with empty spaces to match desired length?

Comment: I can not get the same error you are referencing when having one entry. Can you provide a specific input case (using inline code and not a screenshot, so it's easy to copy/paste)?

Comment: I am not able to copy the code as it is secured. I will try to type it and update it soon. I am getting error like "too few values for argument EMPNUMARRAY" when it tried giving one entry EmpNumArray.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement does not meet using Dwl you can create your custom transformer and use that to achieve the required result.